# Neo4j Cypher - Create an homomorphic transformation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to process an homomorphic transformation onto some of my node's properties in Neo4j (3.5.12).

I want to do this in order to anonymize these properties. Homomorphism is really important there, as I want my referential to remain comparable with previous versions as I update my graph's data with new inputs.

Ideally, I also would like this transformation to keep the data looking normal. By that I mean that I don't want to simply hash the input data, but to keep it look "human", as it will be used by analysts and for demonstration purpose.

Here is what I would like to have as output from my cypher request:

```
"PAUL" -> "DEAN"
```

It feels like it could be resolved with some dict ({P:D, A:E, E:A, L:N...}, but I haven't found any way to feed the `replace()` function with one of those.

I'm kinda new to Cypher so maybe I missed a way to do it natively, or through some APOC function, but didnt find anything convincing on the lib neither.

Should I write a udf for this ?

Comment: Probably using a custom procedure is the way to go, as you can define in Java whatever you want

Comment: If you use a simple homomorphic transformation, it would not be very secure, as that would be the easiest thing to reverse engineer.

Comment: I agree about the reverse engineering issue, should not be an issue in the current situation. Still, what if I was ready to use homomorphic hashing ? Didn't find anything in this domain either in the APOC procedures.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something more secure than a homomorphic transformation, and you do not need to get back the original string, you could consider using the [apoc.util.sha1](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/misc/text-functions/#text-functions-hashing) function to generate an SHA-1 hash.

Note: SHA-1 is supposed to be more secure than MD5, but [recently](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014.pdf) SHA-1 has been found to be pretty weak. Nevertheless, it might be good enough for your needs.